MFC Dockable panes. How to reopen them once closed
While trying to improve my MFC skills, I stumbled upon this very annoying situation.
When I close a dockable pane, I am unable to find a way to reopen it again.
A search here revealed Owen had the same issue here
Unfortunately, I cannot comment on there, hence this new question.
For the record, I've also figured out the registry keys one needs to delete to get the panes again, as pointed out by Christian in that thread.
I have also figured out the use of m_bSaveState = FALSE; as pointed out by Papsicle
But I would like to have them shown again from a menu item.
Thanks in advance for your replies
I searched through the sample code, and searched online, but I was unable to find an answer

Checked the documentation, and found that the CDockablePane class has a ShowPane() member. Check it out.

You may not even need to do anything yourself. Right-clicking on the toolbar(s) or certain areas on the dockable panes displays a pop-up menu containing a list of the dockable panes in checkbox-style menu-items. So the user can simply show/hide the panes. This is already implemented by the framework. Unless I'm missing something...

Now I don't know if I should "answer" my question, so it would be marked as answered, or just edit it (as I have already done).
Mods / more experienced members, please let me know, or take action.
Thanks

Please don't edit an answer into your question. If you have found the solution post a proper answer. Doing this allows future visitors to see that a question has a solution easily.

As it turned out it is as simple as per @Constantine Georgiou's comment.
void CMainFrame::ShowConnectionPane()
{
    m_wndConnectionView.ShowPane(true, false, true);
}

Ευχαριστώ πολύ

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
